# Showing that a subspace of $l^2$ is closed in $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

I found this problem that asks to prove that

> the subspace of $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, where $M = [\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty∈l^2(\mathbb{N}) \mid \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{1+e^{in}}{n^{3/2}}x_n=0]$ 
>   is closed in $l^2(j \in \mathbb{N})$.

How should I approach this to fit the inner product definition? I would appreciate any guidance on the mechanics.

What I know:

- $l^2$ space is closed if it contains all of its limit points.
- Given a subspace V of a Hilbert space, $\mathcal H$, we define the orthogonal complement of V to be $V^{\perp}:=[{f\in\mathcal H |\langle f,g\rangle,∀g \in V}] $
- $V^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal H$, where $\langle f,g\rangle=0$, $∀g \in V$. Need to show that since the inner product is continuous, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\langle f_n,g\rangle = \langle f,g\rangle$ ⇒ $\langle f,g\rangle=0$, and so $f\in V^{\perp}$.

Comment: Do you mean $$M = [\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty∈l^2|\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{1+e^{in}}{n^{3/2}}x_n=0]?$$

If so, try to prove that $y_n=\dfrac{1+e^{in}}{n^{3/2}}$ is in $\ell^2$ and let $V=\{y_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $M=V^\perp$ and so it is closed.

Comment: $M$ is the kernel of an obvious (continuous) linear functional.

Comment: For some $y \in l^2, \|y\| = 1$, let $P(x)  = x - \langle x,y \rangle y$. It is an orthogonal projection on the closed subspace you want.

Comment: I changed $a_n$ in the sum to $x_n$. Please check to make sure this is correct, and fix it if necessary. Also, please don't use `<` and `>` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$. Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for this. That fixes the symbols and the spacing, both.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is the orthogonal complement of the space spanned by the vector $\bigl\{(1+e^{in})/n^{3/2}\bigr\}_{n=1}^\infty$?